# adding Form Validation Javascript of jquery?

Tags: forms, input, jquery-validate, validation

How can I add inline Validation to make sure a choice of radio input must be selected

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function choosePage() {
        if(document.getElementById('weightloss').form1_option1.checked) {
            window.location.replace( "http://google.com/" );
        }
        if(document.getElementById('weightloss').form1_option2.checked) {
            window.location.replace( "http://yahoo.com/" );
        }
    }
</script>

<form id="weightloss">
     <input type="radio" id="form1_option1" name="weight-loss" value="5_day" class="plan">
     <label for="form1_option1"> 5 Day - All Inclusive Price</label><br>
     <input type="radio" id="form1_option2" name="weight-loss" value="7_day">
     <label for="form1_option2"> 7 Day - All Inclusive Price</label><br>
     <input type="button" value="Place Order" alt="Submit button" class="orange_btn" onclick="choosePage()">
</form>
```

Comment: Edited post to include a code block so all the tags showed up...

Comment: why don't you select one of the radios by default ?

Answer (score 0):

you are using `document.getElementById('weightloss')` but infact there is no any element which has id `'weightloss'`.

Try with this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function choosePage() {
        if(document.getElementById('form1_option1').checked) {
            window.location.replace( "http://google.com/" );
        }
        if(document.getElementById('form1_option2').checked) {
            window.location.replace( "http://yahoo.com/" );
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: weightloss is the ID on the form

Comment: all i want is to further add validation to my code above..it works perfect...doing what i want it to do...if i choose one choice it goes to google..if another it goes to yahoo.com..thats perect..but what i want is if a user try to submit before...it should prompt them to choose one.

Comment: key id only works when all radios are named the same, but pass different values...radio group.

Answer (score 0):

You just had to make js evaluate the form first.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function choosePage() {
        if(document.forms["weightloss"]["form1_option1"].checked == true) {
            window.location.replace( "http://google.com/" );
        }
        if(document.forms["weightloss"]["form1_option2"].checked == true) {
            window.location.replace( "http://yahoo.com/" );
        }
        else { alert('Please choose an option'); } // for inline alerts see below.
    }
</script>
```

For inline text alerts try the following:

```
    else { my_message.innerHTML = "Please choose an option" }
```

Add an element to your page to contain the message:

```
    <p id="my_message"></p> <!-- when the form submits empty your message will appear here.
```

Comment: this is perfect..anyway to make the alert inline html text?

Comment: Hey Dawson what if i have about 20 questions?

Comment: Updated my answer for your inline text request.

Comment: Form validation can become an entire project. Especially, if you have a ton of fields that HAVE to be validated, or your users are entering data you didn't expect. A shorter answer... although not always the most elegant - 20 questions / 20 validations / 20 messages is sometimes the easiest way to go.

Comment: There are ways to loop through the form, and catch all of the empty, yet required fields. It is more elegant, but it goes beyond the scope of your question. Do a google search for JavaScript form validation. Better yet, do what you can with server-side scripting PHP, ASP, etc. Client-side validation can be exploited/bypassed pretty easy.